# How to import bulk users in WSO2 API Manager with custom Claim URL and Value

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I need to register over a million users to WSO2 APIM but the documentation does not provide a sample .csv/.xls file structure [Bulk Import of Users](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance510/Bulk+Import+of+Users). 
I need to add this users with a username, password, claimurl and value, and a custom role. Does anyone know how to do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sample file is hosted on [GitHub here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tmkasun/0efeb56eb65cdb76a05ac88c9f26d5ff/raw/220beacac268227ae1baa5968dace6a465e6d662/sample_users.csv). Structure is like this

```
UserName,Password,Claims,
chris2,chris123,http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress=dracusds123@gmail.com,http://wso2.org/claims/role=admin
```

Credit to [Kasun's Knnections](http://me.knnect.com/blog/wso2-enterprise-store-importing-users-in-bulk-through-management-console/)